How does this voltage level shifter work
I’m using a level shifter (NXS0108-Q100) to adapt voltage level between my microcontroller (1.8v) and a component that works on 3.6v. I’m a bit confused on how each I/O cell of the level shifter works. I do not understand the condition that allows a current to flow through pull-up resistors. Can someone please explain?


Current will always flow through the left pull-up resistor if the voltage on terminal A is different from the voltage VCC(A). The amount of current is proportional to this voltage difference (I=U/R).
The same applies for the right resistor.
These pull-up resistors make sure that the voltage levels on terminals A or B are defined, thus not floating. If they were floating (i.e. having random voltage) there would be kind of chaotic behaviour of this circuit.
